# Xcode doesn't measure GPU utilization with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I have launched Xcode's template project for SpriteKit (a rotating aircraft) on an iPhone 6. Much to my surprise Xcode reported no GPU utilization, while at same time I had 800 sprite nodes on the screen and FPS dropped from 60 to 30.
I thought SpriteKit used GPU for its rendering. Is it Xcode or is it me and my lack of knowledge?

[image: Xcode]

Comment: Your app is probably using Metal which reduces the GPU load. However, a zero load seems to me to be a bug in regards to the reporting instrument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FPS Debug Gauge and GPU Report are only available on OpenGL ES games. Sprite Kit now supports Metal devices (any device with an A7 chip, so iPhone 5S+) which means it will not use OpenGL ES. So a workaround is to simply tell Sprite Kit to use OpenGL ES instead of Metal, and this should make the FPS Debug Gauge and GPU Report work again. **Remember to switch back to Metal before releasing your game!** Below is a quote from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/qa/qa1904/_index.html) which details how to switch to OpenGL.

> By default, SpriteKit and SceneKit render with Metal in iOS 9 and OS X
>   El Capitan, however, there is a facility to use OpenGL.
>
> To do that:
>    1. Edit your app's Info.plist 
>    2. Add the PrefersOpenGL key with a bool value of YES
>
> Important: For optimal performance, Metal rendering in SpriteKit and
>   SceneKit is enabled by default. Setting PrefersOpenGL rendering key is
>   not recommended unless it is determined necessary for other reasons.

Also for more information about the FPS Debug Gauge and the GPU Report see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ToolsOverview/ToolsOverview.html)

Please remember to report this bug to Apple.